# install j2me app into nokia5130 mobile

Tags: java-me, nokia, midlet

I have develop a small application in midlet. Now i need to install this app into my nokia mobile(5130 xpressmusic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create .jar and .jad files of that application ( sun-toolkit provides options to create those ) and move these files in your phone and install them as regular application :)